# How to check if my hadoop is running in pseudo distributed mode?

Tags: hadoop, mode

I installed hadoop quite a while ago but I somehow have forgotten if I installed in pseudo distributed mode or not.How can I check it? while my hadoop is running

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To know if you are running hadoop in Standalone or Pseudo distributed mode, verify your configuration files. Below information might help.

[image]

Comment: On hadoop version 3 this doesn't seem to work anymore.  I've been using "yarn.resourcemanager.address"

Answer (score 3):

The tool jps lists out all running Java processes. From the console you can run

```
$ jps
```

and check whether JobTracker, TaskTracker and the HDFS daemons are running.

Comment: How do I distinguish between the Single node and Pseudo distributed?

Comment: @Romantic Electron: If you are running pseudo-distributed mode, you need namenode, secondarynamenode and datanode daemons running.

Answer (score 1):

Check your configuration files:-

Go to directory where hadoop configurations are kept (/etc/hadoop in case of Ubuntu)
Look at slaves and masters files, if both have only localhost or (local IP) it is pseudo-distributed. In case slaves file is empty it is standalone.